# Cryptic clue: Mishearing 'Til Tuesday

Tags: cryptic-clues

Mishearing 'Til Tuesday, I got crazy as icy shirts and the thing at hand induces fear. (4/2/5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> This is scary

Mishearing 'Til Tuesday,

> The band ['Til Tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27Til_Tuesday) had a single called "Voices Carry" in which one of the lines is 
>  "*Hush hush, keep it down now, voices carry*" 
>  often misheard as 
>  "*Hush hush, keep it down now,* **this is scary**"

I got crazy as icy shirts

> *"as icy shirts"* is an anagram of *"this is scary"*

the thing at hand induces fear.

> The thing at hand is *this*, which induces fear (is scary).